# leaflet.js markers not showing up

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, leaflet

My code isn't showing the markers all of the time on the leaflet map.  My code is below.  And below the code is the "view source" I get.  As you can see markers are created with locations in my code but just don't show on the map.  Any ideas?

my website is here and if you view the source you can see that we are trying to make the markers.  https://pursuer.herokuapp.com/maps/

```
{% load leaflet_tags %}

<head>

    {% leaflet_js %}
    {% leaflet_css %}

    <style>

    .leaflet-container {  /* all maps */
        width:  600px;
        height: 400px;
    }

    #yourmap {
        width:  1600px;
        height: 700px;
    }
    #sidebar{
        float: right;
        }

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="sidebar">
        {% block sidebar %}
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="/accounts/login/">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="/setup/">Setup Your Device</a></li>
        </ul>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
{% if latest_device_list %} 

 <script type="text/javascript">
var userArray = new Array();
  function map_init_basic (yourmap, options) {
   var marker = null;

  // map.setView([26.2406685,-80.1665045], 12);
 //map.locate({setView:true, maxZoom: 8});
     {% for device in latest_device_list %}


             var popupText = null;
            {% if user_imei.User_Alias %} 
                popupText='{{user_imei.User_Alias}}';

            {% else %} 

                popupText = {{device.Device_IMEI}};
             {% endif %}
                marker = new L.marker([{{device.Device_Lat}}, {{device.Device_Lon}}])
                .bindPopup("<h3>"+popupText+"</h3>")
                .addTo(yourmap);
                user = {{device.Device_IMEI}};
                userArray[user] = marker;


    {% endfor %} 
     }
    function update_position()
    {

    {% for device in latest_device_list %}

      var popupText = null;


                popupText = {{device.Device_IMEI}};

        userArray[{{device.Device_IMEI}}].setLatLng(new L.LatLng([{{device.Device_Lat}}, {{device.Device_Lon}}]))
        .bindPopup("<h3>"+popupText+</h3>")
        .update();

     {% endfor %} 
      // pan to last device location
     yourmap.panTo(new L.LatLng(marker.getLatLng()),yourmap.getZoom());
    window.setTimeout(update_position,50);
    }
     update_position();
    </script>

     {% else %}
    <p>No Devices are available.</p>
    {% endif %}
  {% leaflet_map "yourmap" callback="window.map_init_basic" %}   

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `"` after `popupText+` for the closing H3 tag in your second popup binding.
See `"<h3>"+popupText+</h3>"`

Comment: Thank you that seems to be the problem!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The issue is that your locations are being output as question marks rather than numbers. You could find this issue by simply viewing the source code of the page, or using [debug extensions](http://debugbrowser.com/).

The problem is on the server level, rather than Leaflet.

Comment: That's only 2 locations , the rest are fine.